# Encrypt .net assemblies/Anti debug techniques

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, encryption, obfuscation

I'm looking for a way to encrypt .net assemblies(exe, dll) or apply anti-debug techniques. I know that the assemblies don't contain native byte code but CIL Code and can be easily decompiled.
 Honestly I have to say I am quite new to .NET. I come from a web-developer background and C# is just a hobby so I don't really need to encrypt my executables but I wondered how solutions like dotfuscator might work.
I also know that the files have to be decrypted in memory in order to execute them but this is the same with assemblies containing native code. 
What I don't want is a discussion whether encrypting .NET executables is useful or not. I am just interested in the theoretical approach one can take to apply encryption or anti-debug techniques (control-flow-obfuscation for example).
As you can see from the example and the related question below, my knowledge is far below ZERO. I am the typical application coder who is happy if the code compiles and runs but I'd like to dig deeper.

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            if(1 < 2) 
            {
                if(3 == 3)
                {
                    if ("a" != "b")
                    {
                        if(0 != 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Could the useless conditions be labeled as control-flow-obfuscation?
Please share your suggestions, any link that might be interesting or book recommendations.

Comment: Obfuscating code is counter-productive since it makes the code more complicated for developers which usually translates into more obscure bugs. The key thing developers should strive for is clean easy to understand code which generally translates into fewer bugs and better maintainability.

Comment: An important point, i guess, would be that this is not 'encryption', what you're asking is obfuscation. you could try to 'encrypt' the code as a dll and then assembly.load the decrypted data, effectively deploying encrypted rubbish with your app; however, for this to have at least any hope of success you would need to write an unmanaged wrapper (c++ app) with high entropy inside that would decrypt the managed code and execute it. Overall, the delay might be significant for a questionable benefit.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial tools which can help you obfuscate your code like [Dotfuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview). Another option is to compile your MSIL to native code using [ngen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.100).aspx).

I think and hope that your custom 'control-flow obfuscation' gets optimized away when building in release.

Comment: I will take a look at ngen. Additionally I didn't know about the optimization during build precess. I will test this tonight and take a look at the decompiled code.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can find the optimize code option in your project settings. This is only MSIL optimization, which is not as much as during JIT compilation. But the if-conditions you used are based on constants so easy to determine that they will always be true. Therefore my guess is that they will be optimized away, but it's always good to check.

Comment: You were right, the conditions got optimized away.